# Azure ADF Get Pipeline Run - What is the message attribute?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-adf

Microsoft ADF has a set of apis to get the status of a pipeline run.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get

In the response, there is an attribute called `message`.

`message | string | The message from a pipeline run.`

How can I set this attribute in the pipeline?

Comment: Your link seems like a private DevOps repo to me. Is it intended for public sharing? Coz seems like credential is needed to view your response.

Comment: @ray linked my build pipeline there. :facepalm: hope the corporate police is not on their way.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set it to activity to be able to access the error message from activity and assign it to a variable as below.

```
@activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].Message
```

For more information follow this [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/205748/adf-getting-the-error-message-of-a-previous-activi.html)

Comment: This is the error message. Can the message be set if the status is Succeeded?